# Is there an OTF ot TTF version of the FourierNC math font OTF?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, fourier

I want to use the math formulas rendered with FourierNC math font on my website.

And I'd like to use the same math font for math symbols within text describing formulas on my website.

But I couldn't find OTF of TTF version of FourierNC font.

Is any option to convert LaTeX font to OTF or TTF?

Thank you!

Comment: Converting a Math Type1 font to OTF is not an straightforward task.  If you need text and math OTF fonts matching NewCentury SchoolBook, why not use the TeX Gyre Schola family?

Comment: Daniel, as I see, TeX Gyre Schola looks different and wider than FourierNC. I'd like to use the same font in TeX formulas and on the website.  
Maybe Fourier (not FourierNC) exists in OTF version?

Comment: Yes it does, you can give it a try with `\usepackage{fourier-otf}`. The font itself is called Erewhon-Math.otf as it is meant for a math companion for the Erewhon text fonts which are an OTF version of Adobe's Utopia.

Comment: @DanielFlipo I’ve turned your comment into a Community Wiki answer, so this question will  no longer be marked as unanswered.

Comment: @DanielFlipo FourierNC is for New Century Schoolbook, not Utopia, which is what you get from fourier-otf.

Comment: @egreg You are right, please note that  I mentionned TeXGyre Schola first.  But the `fourierNC` package uses the fourier glyphs with different metrics afaik, so `fourier-otf` might suit Denis's needs…

Comment: @DanielFlipo No: `fourierNC` uses math letters specially tailored to accompany NCS.

Answer (score 3):

The `fouriernc` package provides a LaTeX math font setup for
NC Schoolbook. It borrows latin letters from NC Schoolbook (reduced at 93%), greek letters and math symbols from the `fourier` package.

The TeXGyre family provides `TeX Gyre Schola` and `TeX Gyre Schola Math` as OTF replacements for NC Schoolbook. Erewhon-Math is an OTF replacement for the fourier fonts.

I would suggest this kind of setting for an OTF replacement of `fouriernc`:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}[Scale=0.93] % Text
% Math: mix of Erewhon and Schola
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[Scale=0.93,
    range={up/{latin,Latin,num}, it/{latin,Latin,num},
           bfup/{latin,Latin,num}, bfit/{latin,Latin,num}}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! As far as I can tell, this is a near perfect replacement of 'fouriernc'. Just a minor note: There is a slash missing after 'bfit'.

Comment: Indded, thanks I corrected my answer.